# set custom headers dynamically in express app to be accessible by angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

[image]i am quiet new to express . I have searched a lot and unable to find the answer.
i am receiving headers in my express app, but when i try to set those headers to be accessible by angular, it returns undefined. how ever hard coded header appears perfectly at angular end in networks tab of chrome. Here is the code

> express code

```
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'];
var app = express();

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
var token=req.header('x-access-token');
//var token='123'
console.log(token);
res.set('x-access-token',token);
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
console.log('server started. Listening on port '+3000);
});
```

> Angular code

```
$http.get($scope.windowURL

    ).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.token=headers('x-access-token')
            console.log($scope.token);
            alert($scope.token)

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('notoken')

        });
```

and i am getting 'undefined' in headers if set dynamically by express app.

Comment: what do you mean by hardcoded header exactly?

Comment: @Rolijhon if i set the value of token=123 in above code. which will be passed to  res.set('x-access-token',token); in express

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the hearders from your request if possible? and does the `console.log(token)` outputs as expected?

Comment: @Rolijhon added the screen and yes console.log is returning token as expected.

Comment: how about the request headers? that's the response headers responded by the node server.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the header, before finishing the response with res.sendFile();

```
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'];
var app = express();

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {

     var token=req.header('x-access-token');
     //var token='123'
     console.log(token);
     res.set('x-access-token',token);
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
     console.log('server started. Listening on port '+3000);
});
```